# Node ACL with individual resources?

Tags: node.js, express

The library in question is here: [node_acl](https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl)

So let's say I'm making a blog and have a role called writer set up as follows:

```
acl.allow('writer', 'blog', ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
```

The routes this would protect would be something like:

```
app.get('/blog/:blogID', acl.middleware(), blogs.show)
app.post('/blog', acl.middleware(), blogs.create)
app.put('/blog/:blogID', acl.middleware(), blogs.edit)
app.delete('/blog/:blogID', acl.middleware(), blogs.remove)
```

The thing is, I obviously don't want them to be able to delete or edit each other's blog posts which this would allow because they're allowed access to all blogs. The only way I thought of solving this would be to have every user have their own role and each resource would be named something like 'blog-blog1ID', 'blog-blog2ID', etc., but that doesn't seem like a very good idea. Thoughts?